# Setting up monitoring authentication file.AMSetupServlet.processRequest: > errorjava.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: openam

I get error when I install openam from existing deployment on command line.

Environment:jdk 1.7.0_60+OpenAM11
My configuration file is:

```
ADMIN_PWD=*******
SERVER_URL=http://openam.example.com:8080
locale=en_US
PLATFORM_LOCALE=en_US
BASE_DIR=/root/openam
AM_ENC_KEY=
DEPLOYMENT_URI=/openam
AMLDAPUSERPASSWD=*****************
SERVER_HOST=openam.example.com

# Embedded configuration data store
DATA_STORE=embedded
DIRECTORY_SSL=SIMPLE
DIRECTORY_SERVER=openam.example.com
DIRECTORY_PORT=50389
DIRECTORY_ADMIN_PORT=4444
DIRECTORY_JMX_PORT=1689
ROOT_SUFFIX=dc=example,dc=com
DS_DIRMGRDN=cn=Directory Manager
DS_DIRMGRPASSWD=*********

DS_EMB_REPL_FLAG=embReplFlag
DS_EMB_REPL_REPLPORT1=58989
DS_EMB_REPL_HOST2=localhost
DS_EMB_REPL_ADMINPORT2=5444
DS_EMB_REPL_REPLPORT2=50889
existingserverid=http://www.openam.example.com:8080/openam

LB_SITE_NAME=lb
LB_PRIMARY_URL=http://lb.example.com/openam
LB_SESSION_HA_SFO=true
```

/root/openam/install.log ：
Setting up monitoring authentication file.AMSetupServlet.processRequest: errorjava.lang.NullPointerException

```
at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.BootstrapCreator.getBootStrapURL(BootstrapCreator.java:190)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.BootstrapCreator.update(BootstrapCreator.java:105)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.BootstrapCreator.updateBootstrap(BootstrapCreator.java:83)
        at com.sun.identity.common.configuration.ServerConfigXMLObserver.update(ServerConfigXMLObserver.java:108)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.processRequest(AMSetupServlet.java:658)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.doPost(AMSetupServlet.java:583)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the last step to success. But I didn't meet the same problem when I install it from web browser.

How can I fix this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you can install it correctly from the web, my advice is that you install it from the web, then go to your installation folder, there is a file called install.log, which containes all the install log, and in the end of the file, you will find the installed configuration similar to the install configuration file you posted in your question, then you can compare whats went wrong.